# JQuery sortable, dragging between two lists, cancelling the drop: How to animate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-animate, drag

I have two HTML lists, and am using JQuery sortable to drag between them.  This works perfectly.

The *receive* event is raised upon dropping a dragged list item into the second list. In this event handler, in some circumstances I am calling

```
$(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
```

which cancels the drop and returns the list item to its original position in the first list.

My question is, how can I animate the movement of the list item back to its original position?  At the moment the item snaps straight back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to side-step this issue by using a combination of jqueryUI's [draggable and sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable).

Comment: How exactly? Did you just change the behavior off your application?

Comment: yes, please explain. if you're going to answer your own question, please add enough detail for others to follow.